# Is Firestore for Node.js eventually moving to the new modular v9 used in Web?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this, but not sure where this would go! I am building an app with Firebase Firestore and Functions and would like to use the same query snippets between the front and the backend occasionally, but now the v9 syntax is much different than the v8 syntax. Will we eventually see the same v9 syntax on the Node.js side?

***Update:***

Modular syntax still isn't working after updating to Node 16. Maybe my code snippet is wrong? TSLint is underlining usage of `db` in `updateDoc()` with the error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(firestore: Firestore, path: string, ...pathSegments: string[]): DocumentReference<DocumentData>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'FirebaseFirestore.Firestore' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("C:/Users/dougl/Documents/GitHub/fire-react-base/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index").Firestore'.
      Type 'Firestore' is missing the following properties from type 'Firestore': type, app, toJSON
  Overload 2 of 3, '(reference: CollectionReference<unknown>, path?: string | undefined, ...pathSegments: string[]): DocumentReference<unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Firestore' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CollectionReference<unknown>'.
      Type 'Firestore' is missing the following properties from type 'CollectionReference<unknown>': type, id, path, parent, and 3 more.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(reference: DocumentReference<unknown>, path: string, ...pathSegments: string[]): DocumentReference<DocumentData>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Firestore' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentReference<unknown>'.
      Type 'Firestore' is missing the following properties from type 'DocumentReference<unknown>': converter, type, firestore, id, and 3 more.ts(2769)
```

**Firebase Function:**

```
"use strict";
import functions = require("firebase-functions");
import {DocumentSnapshot, getFirestore} from "firebase-admin/firestore";
import { doc, increment, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin";

const fire = initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = getFirestore(fire);

export const onMessageCreated = functions.firestore
    .document("messages/{messageId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap: DocumentSnapshot, context: functions.EventContext) => {
        const newValues = snap.data();
        if (!newValues) {
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("newValues: ");
            console.log(newValues);
        }

        try {
            const allPromises: Array<Promise<any>> = [];

            await updateDoc(doc(db, "site", "counts"), {
                messages: increment(1)
            }).then(() => {
                console.log(`Incremented messageCount`)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error(`Error incrementing messageCount: ${error}`)
            })

            return Promise.all(allPromises);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return;
        }
});
```

**Functions package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.6.8",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.19.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Using `getFirestore()` from Admin SDK and `updateDoc()` from client SDK won't work correctly... For Admin SDK, you'll still have to use `db.doc("col/docId").update({...})`

Comment: Correct, this is the original question I asked. Can Firestore v9 (modular) syntax be used instead of v8 syntax for Node.js, but based on @Frank's response below, it seems the v9 syntax should be able to be used if you upgrade Node.js. Trying to figure out if anyone has achieved this in practice!

Comment: Admin SDK isn't fully modular like the web SDK atm. Just the imports like `getAuth()`, `getFirestore()` are... rest most of the things are name-spaced.

Comment: That's the vibe I am getting after testing a bit, but based on @Frank's response below, it seems it should be possible to use the v9 syntax in Node.js.

Answer (score 2):

From version 10 on, the Admin SDK for Node.js supports the same modular syntax as version 9 and higher of client-side JavaScript SDK's. To get started have a look at the documentation on [Upgrade to Node.js SDK Admin SDK v10 (modular SDK)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-node-v10) .

Comment: That should help, thank you, but shouldn't the docs show the updated v9 syntax for the Node.js tab? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: From how I read it the namespaced syntax is still preferred for the Admin SDK, but if you feel that's not the case please leave feedback on the relevant documentation page(s).

Comment: Hi, see edit after trying to update to node 16